# How to get pixel coordinates of object after rendering the scene as image in pyrender?

Tags: python, trimesh, pyrender

I am trying to obtain the pixel coordinates (x, y) of the object that is rendered using pyrender. The aim is to get the bounding box coordinates of that object. I use OffScreenRenderer to render the scene.

```
r = pyrender.OffscreenRenderer(viewport_width=640,
                            viewport_height=480,
                            point_size=1.0)
color, depth = r.render(scene)
```

Available info: camera_to_world pose matrix

First I tried to plot the centroid of the object as below:

```
x, y = trimesh_mesh.centroid[:2]
height, width = image.shape[:2]
x = int(x * width)
y = int(y * height)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following:
[image plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaIAn.png)

Similary the bounding box plot for same object is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gJUb.png)

Does anyone know how I can get the exact centroid and box coordinates of the rendered object? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it by now? If so, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view`.

Use it like so:

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.object   # object you want the coordinates of
vertices = obj.data.vertices   # you will get the coordinates of its vertices

for v in vertices:
    # local to global coordinates
    co = v.co @ obj.matrix_world
    # calculate 2d image coordinates
    co_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, camera, co)
    render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
    render_size = (
        int(scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale),
        int(scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale),
    )

    # this is the result
    pixel_coords = (co_2d.x * render_size[0],
                    co_2d.y * render_size[1])

    print("Pixel Coords:", (
          round(pixel_coords[0]),
          round(pixel_coords[1]),
    ))
```

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1008) on the Blender Stack Exchange

Comment: Hi @Finni. Thank you for your answer. I am not using blender api, instead I import trimesh and pyrender to render images from scene. 

I solved the issue differently. I have corresponding binary masks rendered from the scene. Using these masks, I could compute centroid quite easily.